# Invalid Syntax on simple if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

```
import time
print ("Hello and welcome to my text adventure!")
time.sleep(2)
Name = input ("What is your name?")
print ("Hello " + Name )
time.sleep(2)
print ("You must choose between joining the Guild or protecting the Girl.")
time.sleep(3)
G = input ("Which do you choose? Guild/Girl")
if: G = "Guild"
    print ("So you chose the Guild. Interesting.")
else print ("So you chose the Girl. How chivalrous.")
# If statements not working.
```

I don't see how this isn't working, I've tried moving the colon around a bit to see if it would work, to no avail... I'm very new to this, it's for my A-Level computing coursework so I need help...

Comment: @aga *I'm very new to this, it's for my A-Level computing coursework* - Probably this guy is new to python, nothing off-topic in this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial syntax error which is unlikely to help future visitors

Answer (score 2):

It should have been

```
if G == "Guild":
    ...
else:
    ...
```